# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1. and doesn't run

Tags: python, indexing

Well my code goes like this:

```
r=8.31
tem=np.linspace(425,450,10)

k3=9e3*np.exp(-101000/(r*tem[0]))
k5=5e10*np.exp(-113000/(r*tem[0]))

Cb0=0.0

Cd0=0.0


def eulerd(cb,cd,h,k3,k5):
    valor4=cd+h*(k3*cb-k5*cd)
    return valor4


t=np.linspace(0,2000,20)
h=100

cb=np.array([]) 
cb=np.append(cb,Cb0)
cd=np.array([]) 
cd=np.append(cd,Cd0)

for i in range(t.shape[0]-1):

    valorcdnuevo=eulerd(cb[i],cd[i],h,k3,k5)
    cd=np.append(cd,valorcdnuevo)

plt.plot(t,cd)
```

And when I execute it Python says:

> File "C:/Users/2014/Desktop/ddsdsa.py", line 45, in 
>       valorcdnuevo=eulerd(cb[i],cd[i],h,k3,k5)
>
> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please let us know which programming language this is by adding the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making loop in range between 0 and  t.shape[0] -1 = 19:
[image]

Cb has length 1 on shape[0], therefore that causes an index out of bound exception when i reached value 1